# Access violation when loading a DLL under debugger

Tags: windows, dll, windbg, access-violation

I'm trying to debug a C/C++ Win32 DLL with WinDbg, but at the moment it fails to load with access violation. Here's an edited snippet from the log:

```
ModLoad: 77bd0000 77bd7000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\midimap.dll
ModLoad: ...\PyFM.fmx       <-- THIS IS MY DLL
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for
    ...\FMWrapper.dll - 
ModLoad: ...\FMWrapper.dll   <-- THIS IS ANOTHER DLL I LINK AGAINST
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for
    C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.
    DebugCRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_x-ww_f863c71f\MSVCR90D.dll - 
ModLoad: 10200000 10323000  C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.
    DebugCRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_x-ww_f863c71f\MSVCR90D.dll
(564.970): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
eax=00000000 ebx=05e79b68 ecx=b79a0c61 edx=0049e000 esi=05e79c0c edi=00000080
eip=02887094 esp=0012fa0c ebp=00120000 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010206
DBEngine!Draco::DBPlugIn::MakeCall+0x94:
02887094 c745fcffffffff  
    mov     dword ptr [ebp-4],0FFFFFFFFh ss:0023:0011fffc=????????
```

The stack at this moment appears to be that (WinDbg warns the information may be inaccurate):

```
DBEngine!Draco::DBPlugIn::MakeCall+0x94
DBEngine!Draco::DBPlugIn::LoadStringW+0x7e
```

If I try to continue step by step (although I don't understand assembler instructions) I see that control is passed to `ntdll`; e.g. the next instruction is that:

```
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0x4:
7c90e480 8b1c24
    mov     ebx,dword ptr [esp]  ss:0023:0012f71c=0012f724
```

What I tried: not much, because I don't understand what's going on. Initially I got this error with a non-debug build of the DLL; then I tried to use a debug version, but the error persists. I've suspected manifests and read about them a bit, but nothing seems to be wrong on this part; I even checked that manifest file size is a multiple of 4 :)

Why could it happen? Where I am to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"First chance exceptions" are often normal and can often be ignored.

If you continue the program in the debugger -- not just the next instruction but make it run again; I think it's the 'g' command in WinDbg -- does it work or does it crash with another exception (one which *isn't* a "first chance exception")?

(If you get another "first chance exception" then you can ignore that as well; it would mean the first exception has been dealt with by an exception handler and now you're seeing a completely different exception which may be dealt with as well.)

Some code uses (or rather abuses) exceptions for normal flow-control, making it difficult to run that code under a debugger which is set to break as soon as an exception is thrown. You can configure the debugger to instead only break when an exception is not handled instead.

On the other hand, if continuing the program does result in an unhandled exception then you've probably got a bug in the code (maybe a race condition that is triggered by the debugger changing how fast certain things run or which order they happen to run in), or you're not running the program in the same context as usual (e.g. the current directory, DLL path, environment variables or some other thing is different). Or maybe a DLL you are using explicitly checks for a debugger to try and stop people reverse engineering it (but that is very rare).

Comment: Yes, the main program expects and handles this exceptions and continues on its own, but without my DLL :) As far as I understand what's going on it's that the main program tries to call a function in my DLL and fails. What puzzles me is that it appears to fail before calling: I tried to set a breakpoint in the DLL function and either I set it incorrectly or it was never hit.

Comment: @Mikhail: How is the main program linked to your DLL? Sounds like it's using delay-loading and then not finding the DLL or the functions, perhaps. I'd also try setting the breakpoint in Visual Studio instead of WinDbg; WinDbg is more powerful but the VS debugger is a hell of a lot more user friendly and much better (IMO) when you don't need that extra power. In the VS debugger, make sure you get a solid red circle for the breakpoint, not just an outline (which means your DLL is not loaded (yet) and/or the DLL, its debug symbols and the source code are out of sync).

Comment: thanks for the help; I haven't yet found the root of the problem, but at least I found that I was wrong about the causes: the library loads and actually gets called a couple of times, the exception happens next. Which means all I wrote is not relevant; I'm exploring the code now. I'm somehow not used to IDEs, so WinDbg is better for me; I find it similar to gdb, although harder to use.